# Hide embed using CSS

Tags: html, css, embed, mp4, hidden

I have a browser compatibility issue with .mp4 (Firefox) and I found a solution, but my problem evolved.

Have this :

```
<script src="http://github.com/rafaelp/css_browser_selector/raw/master/css_browser_selector.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<video src="ikitaAnnie.mp4" controls width="800"></video>
<embed type="application/x-vlc-plugin" name="ikitaAnnie" autoplay="no" loop="no" width="800" height="456.8081991" target="ikitaAnnie.mp4" />
```

And this :

```
/* Chrome Only */
.chrome embed {
    display: none;
}

/* Firefox Only */
.gecko video {
    display: none;
}
```

My solution is to hide `<video></video>` for Firefox, and hide `<embed />` for everyone else. The problem is... `display: none;` doesn't work for `<embed />`.

Is it possible to hide `<embed>` using CSS? How?

Comment: the embed itself might get hidden, but whatever plugin (e.g. vlc) is not bound to obey the css. better option would be to remove the embed from the dom completely.

Comment: @MarcB Thanks! Looks like I have to find another way to show .mp4 video to gecko.

Answer (score 1):

Try to emulate `display: none` with:

```
/* Chrome Only */
.chrome embed {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: It did absolutely nothing :( It's probably the plugin's fault.

Comment: It's hard to write a good solution without having a look at entire project, but you can try to overwrite plugin styling by adding ` !important` at the end of each property value.

Comment: It did nothing too :(